# npx react-native run-android error > Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED

Tags: java, react-native, kotlin

by running command npx react-native run-android or npm run android it gives the following error if you know why is this happening please let me know

```
> myApp@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at makeError (/Users/ayan/Documents/myApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/ayan/Documents/myApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/ayan/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/ayan/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

if you know the answer please let me know
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is issue with your java installation. Please Install JDK 11 on your machine. you can install mac with  HomeBrew and on windows use can use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org)

check this message so you can identify this issue
Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

Comment: can you help with the installation guide

Comment: please read this https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command:-

ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

and after that

npx react-native run-android

Or else try to update the gradle version by putting this line into the wrapper properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

Comment: that also not worked for me

Comment: try to update the gradle version

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

chmod 755 android/gradlew

inside your app root folder then run

react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

The reason is my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `xxxx/java/jre1.8xx`;

Change to your `path/jdk-11`; Just running

I hope it will help you

```
------Note this error message:

"Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation."
```

Comment: Is this a solution or fix, or are you asking for help?